# Calling member functions of an object stored in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

This may sound like a newbie question. How do I call a member function of an object stored in a vector ? Supposedly, I have this class:

```
class A {
public:
void foo() {
std::cout << "Hello World"; }
};
```

Then I store some objects in a vector:

```
std::vector<A*> objects;
A* b;
A* c;
A* d;

objects.push_back(b);
objects.push_back(c);
objects.push_back(d);
```

Now I want to create a loop, in which every object stored in the vector would call it's own foo() function. How should I do this ? At first I thought I could just do something like this:

```
objects[2].foo();
```

But it seems that I can't do it like this.

Comment: Try objects[2]->foo()

Comment: Those aren't "objects stored in a vector" those are "object pointers stored in a vector".

Answer (score 4):

[std::vector::operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) returns a reference to the object in std::vector. As your `objects` stores a pointer to `A`, you should call it:

```
objects[2]->foo();
```

> Now I want to create a loop, in which every object stored in the vector would call it's own foo() function. How should I do this

The easiest loop is:

```
for (int i=0; i<objects.size(); ++i)
{
   objects[i]->foo();
}
```

use C++11 for loop:

```
for(auto ep : objects)
{
    ep->foo();
}
```

Or for_each(need to write a small lambda though)

```
for_each(objects.begin(), objects.end(), [](A* ep){ep->foo(); });
```

Side note:
    In practice you'd better store value in STL container.

```
std::vector<A> objects;
for(auto e : objects)
{
    ep.foo();    // call member function by "."
}
```

If you want to store pointer with STL container, better use smart pointer, e.g.

```
#include <memory>
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A> > objects;

objects.push_back(new A());
objects.push_back(new A());
objects.clear(); // all dynamically allocated pointer elements will be de-allocated automatically
```

Comment: Can i ask, why it's better to store values in a STL container, than pointers? And if pointers, than why smart pointers? Is it all about the memory dealocation , for example, when using for clearing the container?

Comment: If you simply call objects.clear() from OP's sample code, it leaks memory. you have to go through every element in STL container delete the memory the pointer is pointing to first.  If you store value or smart pointer, you can do that.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* do this:

```
std::vector<A> objects;
A b;
A c;
A d;

objects.push_back(b);
objects.push_back(c);
objects.push_back(d);

objects[2].foo();
```

Please be a bit more specific about the exact error.  I suspect maybe the whole problem was trying to reference a pointer to an object with "." instead of "->".

But yes, in general:

1) You can save an object, or a pointer to an object, in any STL container

2) You can call any public method of that object upon accessing it from the container.

Answer (score 2):

You have created pointers to class A and not instances. So, you ought to access the method foo with pointer syntax.
i.e

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      objects[i]->foo();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++98 and C++03 (Since the other answers already tell you how to do it in the new standard) you can use std::for_each and the std::mem_fun adapter:

> std::for_each(objects.begin(), objects.end(), std::mem_fun(&A::foo));

The std::for_each applies a function or functor to each of the elements in the range.

The std::mem_fun adapter takes a pointer to a function in its constructor and a pointer to an object as its (first) argument for operator().

This will result in the std::for_each invoking the foo() member function on each element on the array. If your vector had values on it instead of pointer you can use std::mem_fun_ref instead.

As for the error you are getting, remember that your vector is a collection of pointers so you should invoke the functions as follows:

```
objects[index]->foo();
```